# Overriding Telerik Skin with Removing CSS Property

Tags: css, telerik

With Inspect Element, I Discover a part of telerik's skin's CSS code:

```
.RadRotator .rrClipRegion .rrItemsList  {
    margin: 0;
}
```

In inspect element I can remove margin property and I will get a nice result, how to override removing properties?

Comment: did you try to make your own selector heavier, e.g.: div.RadRotator .rrClipRegion .rrItemsList { margin: inherit;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `margin: inherit;` to override the defined margin.

Comment: I just updated my question. I just need to remove margin property and it did not work by setting it into inherit!

Comment: Its hard to imagine what exactly you want and why inherit is not working on your markup, without any demonstration.